# Password not applied when i protect from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

[image]This code is for a button, its supposed to protect all the sheets of another workbook, it works but it doesn't protect them with password i don't know why. It detects `Pass` but for some reason it doesn't protect it. As you can see on the image it detects the password, doesn't apply it tho.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Pass = Sheets("Pass").Range("C5").Value
    If Sheets("Pass").Range("C5").Value <> "" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("G:\SnP\L-3\Nómina\Nómina 1° Turno.xlsm")
        With wb
            For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
            Sheets(i).Protect Password:=Pass, DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
            Next i
            Listop = MsgBox("Listo")
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
            'wb.Close Savechanges:=True
        End With
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Err = MsgBox("Agregar Nueva o Vieja contraseña")
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't know if it's important but i also have the `Unprotect` down below, which is working good.

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Pass = Sheets("Pass").Range("C5").Value
    If Sheets("Pass").Range("C5").Value <> "" Then
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open("G:\SnP\L-3\Nómina\Nómina 1° Turno.xlsm")
        With wb
            For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
            Sheets(i).Unprotect Pass
            Next i
            Listop = MsgBox("Listo")
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        End With
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Err = MsgBox("Agregar Nueva o Vieja contraseña")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked for me. Password:=Pass should be Password:="Pass", but that only caused issues unprotecting on my side.

Comment: Pass is a value on the sheet that's why `Pass = Sheets("Pass").Range("C5").Value` i just tried to verify `Sheets(i).Protect Password:="Pass"` not working either

Comment: OK, it's a scope issue then, I'll give some more detail in answer

Comment: Is the workbook always closed when you run the "protect" code?

Comment: It has to be, since `Workbooks.Open` opens it and rewrites it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's incorrect scope on your "With wb" section.

Try .Sheets wherever you have Sheets in that section to clarify which workbook the sheets belong to.

Comment: All the sheets from the "Nómina 1° Turno.xlsm" workbook are getting protected but without password.

Comment: Ok good, that fixed the first issue. Does it work when replacing your named range with a string?

Comment: Oh i didn't change anything, it was working like that all the time, and no :( the `Dim Pass As String` didn't work out.

Comment: Then I'm stuck. Works fine on my pc using the same code, only changes are the filepath and sheets -> .sheets